# Spring-boot, JPA how to save collection for object

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, collections, one-to-many

I'm trying to save object which have collection of objects e.g. Invoice with collection of InvoiceItems. I got JSON with Invoice and InvoiceItems but after save just Invoice is on the database InvoiceItems are not saved.

Invoice

```
package com.example.demo.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "gp_invoice")
public class GpInvoice {
    private int mGpInvoiceRecid;
    private String mGpInvoiceTitle;
    private String mGpInvoiceNumber;
    private Date mGpInvoiceRelease;
    private Date mGpInvoicePosting;
    private Date mGpInvoiceDelivery;
    private String mGpInvoiceReleaseplace;
    private GpContractor mGpContractorByGpInvoiceContractor;
    private Collection<GpInvoiceitem> mGpInvoiceitemsByGpInvoiceRecid;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GP_INVOICE_RECID", nullable = false)
    public int getGpInvoiceRecid() {
        return mGpInvoiceRecid;
    }

    public void setGpInvoiceRecid(int gpInvoiceRecid) {
        mGpInvoiceRecid = gpInvoiceRecid;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVOICE_TITLE", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getGpInvoiceTitle() {
        return mGpInvoiceTitle;
    }

    public void setGpInvoiceTitle(String gpInvoiceTitle) {
        mGpInvoiceTitle = gpInvoiceTitle;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVOICE_NUMBER", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getGpInvoiceNumber() {
        return mGpInvoiceNumber;
    }

    public void setGpInvoiceNumber(String gpInvoiceNumber) {
        mGpInvoiceNumber = gpInvoiceNumber;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVOICE_RELEASE", nullable = false)
    public Date getGpInvoiceRelease() {
        return mGpInvoiceRelease;
    }

    public void setGpInvoiceRelease(Date gpInvoiceRelease) {
        mGpInvoiceRelease = gpInvoiceRelease;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVOICE_POSTING", nullable = true)
    public Date getGpInvoicePosting() {
        return mGpInvoicePosting;
    }

    public void setGpInvoicePosting(Date gpInvoicePosting) {
        mGpInvoicePosting = gpInvoicePosting;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVOICE_DELIVERY", nullable = false)
    public Date getGpInvoiceDelivery() {
        return mGpInvoiceDelivery;
    }

    public void setGpInvoiceDelivery(Date gpInvoiceDelivery) {
        mGpInvoiceDelivery = gpInvoiceDelivery;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVOICE_RELEASEPLACE", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getGpInvoiceReleaseplace() {
        return mGpInvoiceReleaseplace;
    }

    public void setGpInvoiceReleaseplace(String gpInvoiceReleaseplace) {
        mGpInvoiceReleaseplace = gpInvoiceReleaseplace;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        GpInvoice gpInvoice = (GpInvoice) o;
        return mGpInvoiceRecid == gpInvoice.mGpInvoiceRecid &&
                Objects.equals(mGpInvoiceTitle, gpInvoice.mGpInvoiceTitle) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpInvoiceNumber, gpInvoice.mGpInvoiceNumber) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpInvoiceRelease, gpInvoice.mGpInvoiceRelease) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpInvoicePosting, gpInvoice.mGpInvoicePosting) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpInvoiceDelivery, gpInvoice.mGpInvoiceDelivery) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpInvoiceReleaseplace, gpInvoice.mGpInvoiceReleaseplace);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(mGpInvoiceRecid, mGpInvoiceTitle, mGpInvoiceNumber, mGpInvoiceRelease, mGpInvoicePosting, mGpInvoiceDelivery, mGpInvoiceReleaseplace);
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "GP_INVOICE_CONTRACTOR", referencedColumnName = "GP_CONTRACTOR_RECID", nullable = false)
    public GpContractor getGpContractorByGpInvoiceContractor() {
        return mGpContractorByGpInvoiceContractor;
    }

    public void setGpContractorByGpInvoiceContractor(GpContractor gpContractorByGpInvoiceContractor) {
        mGpContractorByGpInvoiceContractor = gpContractorByGpInvoiceContractor;
    }


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "gpInvoiceByGpInvitInvoicerecid")
    public Collection<GpInvoiceitem> getGpInvoiceitemsByGpInvoiceRecid() {
        return mGpInvoiceitemsByGpInvoiceRecid;
    }

    public void setGpInvoiceitemsByGpInvoiceRecid(Collection<GpInvoiceitem> gpInvoiceitemsByGpInvoiceRecid) {
        mGpInvoiceitemsByGpInvoiceRecid = gpInvoiceitemsByGpInvoiceRecid;
    }
}
```

InvoiceItem

```
package com.example.demo.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "gp_invoiceitem")
public class GpInvoiceitem {
    private int mGpInvitRecid;
    private String mGpInvitName;
    private String mGpInvitDescription;
    private double mGpInvitPricenet;
    private int mGpInvitAmount;
    private String mGpInvitUnit;
    private int mGpInvitVat;
    private double mGpInvitPriceamountnet;
    private double mGpInvitPricevat;
    private double mGpInvitPricegross;
    private GpInvoice mGpInvoiceByGpInvitInvoicerecid;
    private byte mGpInvit50;
    private String mGpInvitReason;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_RECID", nullable = false)
    public int getGpInvitRecid() {
        return mGpInvitRecid;
    }

    public void setGpInvitRecid(int gpInvitRecid) {
        mGpInvitRecid = gpInvitRecid;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_NAME", nullable = false, length = 50)
    public String getGpInvitName() {
        return mGpInvitName;
    }

    public void setGpInvitName(String gpInvitName) {
        mGpInvitName = gpInvitName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_DESCRIPTION", nullable = true, length = 200)
    public String getGpInvitDescription() {
        return mGpInvitDescription;
    }

    public void setGpInvitDescription(String gpInvitDescription) {
        mGpInvitDescription = gpInvitDescription;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_PRICENET", nullable = false, precision = 0)
    public double getGpInvitPricenet() {
        return mGpInvitPricenet;
    }

    public void setGpInvitPricenet(double gpInvitPricenet) {
        mGpInvitPricenet = gpInvitPricenet;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_AMOUNT", nullable = false)
    public int getGpInvitAmount() {
        return mGpInvitAmount;
    }

    public void setGpInvitAmount(int gpInvitAmount) {
        mGpInvitAmount = gpInvitAmount;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_UNIT", nullable = false, length = 10)
    public String getGpInvitUnit() {
        return mGpInvitUnit;
    }

    public void setGpInvitUnit(String gpInvitUnit) {
        mGpInvitUnit = gpInvitUnit;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_VAT", nullable = false)
    public int getGpInvitVat() {
        return mGpInvitVat;
    }

    public void setGpInvitVat(int gpInvitVat) {
        mGpInvitVat = gpInvitVat;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_PRICEAMOUNTNET", nullable = false, precision = 0)
    public double getGpInvitPriceamountnet() {
        return mGpInvitPriceamountnet;
    }

    public void setGpInvitPriceamountnet(double gpInvitPriceamountnet) {
        mGpInvitPriceamountnet = gpInvitPriceamountnet;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_PRICEVAT", nullable = false, precision = 0)
    public double getGpInvitPricevat() {
        return mGpInvitPricevat;
    }

    public void setGpInvitPricevat(double gpInvitPricevat) {
        mGpInvitPricevat = gpInvitPricevat;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_PRICEGROSS", nullable = false, precision = 0)
    public double getGpInvitPricegross() {
        return mGpInvitPricegross;
    }

    public void setGpInvitPricegross(double gpInvitPricegross) {
        mGpInvitPricegross = gpInvitPricegross;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        GpInvoiceitem that = (GpInvoiceitem) o;
        return mGpInvitRecid == that.mGpInvitRecid &&
                Double.compare(that.mGpInvitPricenet, mGpInvitPricenet) == 0 &&
                mGpInvitAmount == that.mGpInvitAmount &&
                mGpInvitVat == that.mGpInvitVat &&
                Double.compare(that.mGpInvitPriceamountnet, mGpInvitPriceamountnet) == 0 &&
                Double.compare(that.mGpInvitPricevat, mGpInvitPricevat) == 0 &&
                Double.compare(that.mGpInvitPricegross, mGpInvitPricegross) == 0 &&
                Objects.equals(mGpInvitName, that.mGpInvitName) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpInvitDescription, that.mGpInvitDescription) &&
                Objects.equals(mGpInvitUnit, that.mGpInvitUnit);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(mGpInvitRecid, mGpInvitName, mGpInvitDescription, mGpInvitPricenet, mGpInvitAmount, mGpInvitUnit, mGpInvitVat, mGpInvitPriceamountnet, mGpInvitPricevat, mGpInvitPricegross);
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "GP_INVIT_INVOICERECID", referencedColumnName = "GP_INVOICE_RECID", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    public GpInvoice getGpInvoiceByGpInvitInvoicerecid() {
        return mGpInvoiceByGpInvitInvoicerecid;
    }

    public void setGpInvoiceByGpInvitInvoicerecid(GpInvoice gpInvoiceByGpInvitInvoicerecid) {
        mGpInvoiceByGpInvitInvoicerecid = gpInvoiceByGpInvitInvoicerecid;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_50", nullable = false)
    public byte getGpInvit50() {
        return mGpInvit50;
    }

    public void setGpInvit50(byte gpInvit50) {
        mGpInvit50 = gpInvit50;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "GP_INVIT_REASON", nullable = false, length = 30)
    public String getGpInvitReason() {
        return mGpInvitReason;
    }

    public void setGpInvitReason(String gpInvitReason) {
        mGpInvitReason = gpInvitReason;
    }
}
```

Invoice repository

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
public interface InvoiceRepository extends Repository<GpInvoice, Long> {

    void save(GpInvoice invoice);
}
```

Controller

```
@PostMapping(path = "/new")
public void createInvoice(@RequestBody() InvoiceDto gpInvoice) {
    mInvoiceService.saveAndFlush(gpInvoice.invoice, gpInvoice.invoiceItems);
}
```

Service

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void saveAndFlush(GpInvoice invoice, List<GpInvoiceitem> gpInvoiceItem) {
    invoice.setGpInvoiceitemsByGpInvoiceRecid(gpInvoiceItem);
    mInvoiceRepository.save(invoice);
}
```

Why InvoiceItems are not saved?

Answer (score 0):

Given the situation i think you are missing "(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)". This is how your OneToMany mapping should look like -

```
            @OneToMany(mappedBy = "gpInvoiceByGpInvitInvoicerecid", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
            public Collection<GpInvoiceitem> getGpInvoiceitemsByGpInvoiceRecid() {
                return mGpInvoiceitemsByGpInvoiceRecid;
            }
```